# Closed question could be reopened after edit, but already has many downvotes: should I tell the user to create a new one?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, reopen-closed

This is concerning review for reopen votes on this question:

*https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/19326899*

I think the new version of question is acceptable for reopening now. The user has provided an MCVE and context.

However, it has had already more than downvotes. In my experience, this is hardly recoverable.

I was about to recommend to this user to delete his question and reopen a fresh one with the new contents.

In this case the user would have a deleted answer with downvotes (no reputation harm (+ another question which might have a chance to be upvoted (but also a risk to be downvoted too, I admit), instead of a single hard downvoted question.

Also, I don't know the mechanics of question banning, and I'm not sure if this would not harm the user on this side as well.

So, is it a good move for the user to delete and create a new question?

Should I recommend this in comments?

Comment: You could always upvote the question yourself to reduce the negative score (if the question is indeed upvote worthy)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, deleting and re-posting questions to try to subvert the voting system is considered abusive and not appropriate.  If you think the question should be reopened, vote to reopen (having said that, looking at the question it doesn't look like they have a good reproducible example, so while the post is *better*, I'm not sure it's actually good enough yet, although it's outside of my area of expertise so I can't say conclusively), don't suggest that the user attempt to subvert the voting systems.  If they get caught, they'll just be even worse off than they are now.

As for the question ban, it will look at all questions regardless of whether they're deleted or not, so the existing question would still be considered, and if their new question is also poorly received (as I personally suggest it might be) they'd be far worse off than if they continued trying to fix their existing question.

Comment: This is a specific answer to a specific question, no qualms with the logic. But how do you suggest such a question, if well written, gets the attention it now deserves? Wait a couple of days before offering a bounty? Or is this no longer an issue?

Comment: @jpp The question is in the reopen queue, if it were *actually* fixed, it would get reopened (and plausibly attract upvotes from those seeing the improvements), that (along with the edit that improved the question) would mark the question as active again, resulting it in showing up on the tag list, and no longer being closed.  It might get a bit *less* attention than a higher scoring question, but there are still people that look at lower scored questions, and if they feel it really is improved, they're likely to upvote it.  It's not like the question is invisible.

Comment: Fair enough, if the point is to make sure it's *not invisible*, as you say it succeeds. In reality, it will always be less than -4 and avoid the front page. There is no perfect answer, I'd say this is a partial success and the best option.